# Spring Cloud Gateway route builder has missing predicate option

Tags: java, spring-boot, predicate, spring-cloud-gateway

I want to add a predicate to my spring gateway route below

```
public RouteLocator routeLocator(RouteLocatorBuilder builder,
                                     CredentialsAuthRoutePredicateFactory ca) {
        return builder.routes()
                .route("superGraph - get data",r -> r
                        .path( "/alcoholic-alpaca/**")
                        .predicate(...)
```

However, the predicate option is underlined, and this error is showing up:

```
'predicate' is not public in 'org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.builder.BooleanSpec'. Cannot be accessed from outside package
```

How can i access predicate in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`path(String path)` method of `PredicateSpec` is also a predicate (like a special case), so if you want multiple predicates you should call `BooleanSpec`'s `and()` or `or()` method (depends on your scenario) and then call another predicate method, like this:

```
public RouteLocator routeLocator(RouteLocatorBuilder builder, CredentialsAuthRoutePredicateFactory ca) {
    return builder.routes()
            .route("superGraph - get data",
                    r -> r.path( "/alcoholic-alpaca/**")
                        .and() // or() ?
                        .predicate(alpacaPredicate)
                        .filters(f -> f.filter(alpacaFilter))
                        .uri(soberAlpacaUri))
            .build();
}
```